# What does "straight" mean in this context"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

The following context is from a youtube video called Eyes Wide Shut - Red cloak unmasked !!! (film analysis)

"As it often is with Kubrick, clues are given mostly visually rather than in **straight** dialogue"

**straight** definitions
1.
Direct and candid: *a straight answer.*(source thefreedictionary)
2.
not deviating from an indicated pattern
*writes straight humor*
*a straight-A student*(source Merriam Webster)

Are any of these applicable here?

Comment: Yes, the second applies. straight dialogue, outright dialogue

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the most relevant sense is [Merrian-Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/straight) 3.c:

> *straight*: 3.c. free from extraneous matter: unmixed

I would also add *pure* and *undiluted* to that definition. In this case, Kubrick chooses to use visual clues instead of just dialogue alone. *Straight dialogue* here stands for *pure* or *unmixed* *dialogue*; in this case, dialogue *alone*, to the exclusion of other ways of communicating information like music, visual communication, facial expression etc.  We might reword the sentence:

> As it often is with Kubrick, clues are given mostly visually rather in **pure dologue** (i.e. without other the support of other methods of communication in film).